# @ng-select addTag, how to validate after add the new tag?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

i am using [@ng-select/ng-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select)

**html file**

```
<ng-select [items]="_Customers"
           [addTag]="addTagPromise"
           [bindLabel]="'name'"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedCustomer">
</ng-select>
```

**addTag** is working but
**addTagPromise function**
inside already defined values not accessible

**ts file**

```
  _Customers: any[] = [];
  companies = ['company one', 'company Two', 'company three'];
  selectedCustomer;

  ngOnInit() {
     this.companies.forEach((c, i) => {
         this._Customers.push({ id: i, name: c });
     });
  }

  addTagPromise(name) {
    console.log(this._Customers);
     return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({ id: 5, name: name, valid: true });
         }, 1000);
     })
  }
```

printed log is **undefined**

how to access the already defined values inside of addTagPromise function?

Answer (score 4):

Hey sorry if i'm late to the party but the issue is caused by how the binding of "this" is handled. because you are simply a declared method in your class the this is implied (sorry I dont know exactly how that is handled) so the best method is to just change your method to

```
  addTagPromise: (value: any): Promise<any>;
  ngOnInit() {
     ...
     this.addTagPromise = ()=>{
       //Code the function here 
     }

  }
```

doing it this way will make it so that your function's this is binded because an arrow function automatically binds your this.

Again, sorry for the late reply!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong way
try like this:

```
addTagPromise = (name) => {
console.log(this._Customers);
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ id: 5, name: name, valid: true });
     }, 1000);
 }) 
}
```

as a variable function, then you can access all values of class