# How to call a function when addTag is used in ng-select

Tags: angular, binding, tags, angular-ngselect

I am using ng-select in angular to load a list . When searching if the item is not available i have used addTag to add the item to array. But the value is not set to ng-select , also the function is called but cannot close the add tag strip. Below is the code

```
items = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Python'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Node Js'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Java'},
  {id: 4, name: 'PHP', disabled: true},
  {id: 5, name: 'Django'},
  {id: 6, name: 'Angular'},
  {id: 7, name: 'Vue'},
  {id: 8, name: 'ReactJs'},
  
];

addNewCompany(term:string){
  console.log(term);
  this.selected=term;
 
}
```

Below is the html code. I have called the function in addTag attribute as said in the documentation. But it is not binding the value to input box.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 mt-2"> 
                <label for="company_name" class="modal_class ml-2"><i
                        class="uil uil-phone mr-2"></i>Company Name</label>
                        <ng-select [items]="items"
                        bindLabel="name"
                        placeholder="Select item"
                        appendTo="body"
                        [(ngModel)]="selected"
                        [addTag]="addNewCompany"
                        addTagText="Add Company"
                        [closeOnSelect]="true"
                        class="form-control form-control-select validate_input"
                        >
                       </ng-select>
              </div>
```

Comment: Could you create a stackblitz

Comment: This might help you with your problem (sounds like addTag requires special handling): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52780465/ng-select-addtag-how-to-validate-after-add-the-new-tag

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
addNewCompany = (term:string) =>{
   console.log(term);
   this.selected=term;
     
}
```